# Override __new__ of a class which extends Enum

Tags: python, enums, overriding, typeerror, new-operator

A class `Message` extends `Enum` to add some logic. The two important parameters are verbose level and message string, with other optional messages (`*args`). Another class `MessageError` is a special form of the `Message` class in which verbose level is always zero, everything else is the same.

The following code screams `TypeError`:

> TypeError: Enum.**new**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

```
from enum import Enum


class Message(Enum):
    verbose: int
    messages: list[str]

    def __new__(cls, verbose: int, message: str, *args):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self._value_ = message
        return self
    
    def __init__(self, verbose: int, message: str, *args):
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.messages = [self.value] + list(args)


class MessageError(Message):

    def __new__(cls, message: str):
        return super().__new__(cls, 0, message) # <- problem is here!

    def __init__(self, message: str):
        return super().__init__(0, message)


class Info(Message):
    I_001 = 2, 'This is an info'


class Error(MessageError):
    E_001 = 'This is an error'
```

I was expecting that `super().__new__(cls, 0, message)` would call `__new__` from the `Message` class, but it seems that is not the case. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Message.__new__()` is calling the inherited method on the wrong class - `object` instead of `Enum` (or `super()`).

Comment: @jasonharper: Due to `Enum`s oddities, that's not the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Enum`s are unusual (aka weird) in several regards, with creation being the biggest area.  During enum class creation, after the members themselves have been created but before the class is returned, any existing `__new__` is renamed to `__new_member__`<sup>1</sup> and the `__new__` from `Enum` itself is inserted into the class -- this is so calls like `Info('This is an error')` will return the existing member (or raise), and not create a new member.

Your `MessageError.__new__` should look like:

```
    def __new__(cls, message: str):
        return super().__new_member__(cls, 0, message)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In 3.11+ it's also saved as `_new_member_` to follow the pattern of sunder names for enum-specific methods and attributes.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) library.

Comment: There's a typo there: should be `__new_member__` (with double underscores)

Comment: @mahkitah: Nope, most `Enum`-specific special attributes use sunder (single-underscore front and back).

Comment: I got an AttributeError with the sunder, and it works fine with the dunder. I found the dunder in the actual enum code.

Comment: @mahkitah: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @mahkitah: Looks like a change I made in 3.11 (both are supported at that point).  So, yup, I'll update my example.  Thanks!

Comment: I tested it on 3.10 and yes on 3.11 they both work.

Comment: @EthanFurman Helpful as always, thanks a lot! I figured `Enum` has a different path to creating objects because it does its magic on class attributes themselves, but did not know how to handle it properly. Since they both work, which should I use: _sunder_ or _dunder_? Something not related to the original question: in the `Message.__init__()` method, do I need to put a call to `super().__init__()` at the end?

Comment: If you need to run on Pythons prior to 3.11, use `__new_member__`.  Using `super().__init__()` in `Message` is not required, but is good practice and can help with refactoring later (one less thing to worry about).